# Blender saying 91 uses of image when only 6 materials

Tags: python, scripting, materials

I am working on a script that adds materials and it deletes all the materials in the scene if they have no users. Which seems to be working great, but if I check this:

```
bpy.data.images[1].users
```

I get an answer of `91` even though `len(bpy.data.materials)` shows only `6` materials. It is like the image is being held onto in materials that don't even exist anymore. Any ideas why this would be?

#### EDIT

Here is the [script](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B35OsPAJ46kvbUJrYnJhR21BX2M&usp=sharing), steps:

1. Download File
2. Load `JARCH_siding.py` into text editor
3. Run
4. Add Siding `View 3D > Add > Mesh > JARCH Vis > Add Siding`
5. Open Panel `View 3D > Toolbar > JARCH Vis tab`
6. Select `Cycles Material?`
7. Add image file
8. Hit generate a bunch of times
9. Go to node editor and see number of users on image

Comment: maybe multiple objects have that material applied?

Comment: Probably a bug...

Comment: @Vader  nope, 3 objects, 6 materials, 1 mesh, 50 uses of the image. When I restart all the uses are gone as the material was gone so the actual usage was gone.

Comment: hmm, so it's working?

Comment: @Vader not really, since when you run the script next time it starts adding instances back. Should I submit this as a bug?

Comment: @BlendingJake Yes

Comment: You can have multiple images per material, and materials aren't the only things which can use images..

Comment: I know @gandalf3, but materials are the only thing that this image is being applied to and the image is only in the material once

Comment: Is it possible you could upload the script or a .blend?

Comment: scripts up @gandalf3

Comment: So this is officially being considered a bug? OK,  I'll go head and report it.

Comment: bug reported here: https://developer.blender.org/T42523